# The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, curl, slim, guzzle

Although this has multiple answers but still I'm not able to resolve the issue.

1. I'm using Ubuntu stack on AWS
2. I already installed php5-curl and it shows
3. I'm working on TokBox video library using php server side

Whenever I execute my url, I get the exception:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException
Message: The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.
File:     /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php
Line: 72
Trace

#0 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/opentok/opentok/src/OpenTok/OpenTok.php(50): Guzzle\Http\Client->__construct()
#1 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/index.php(58): OpenTok\OpenTok->__construct(45573572, '1be4a65cd4e691d...')
#2 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Helper/Set.php(228): {closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set))
#3 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Helper/Set.php(88): Slim\Helper\Set->Slim\Helper\{closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set))
#4 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(234): Slim\Helper\Set->get('opentok')
#5 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/index.php(80): Slim\Slim->__get('opentok')
#6 [internal function]: {closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(468): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1357): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#10 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#11 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#12 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1302): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#13 /var/www/html/tokboxphpserver/index.php(156): Slim\Slim->run()
#14 {main}
```

Comment: After installing `php5-curl` did you do a restart of Apache so that the new module gets loaded? Furthermore where do you want to have this extension loaded - web server or CLI? Remember that PHP uses different configurations for web server and CLI

Comment: I restarted the apache2 server but still no affect :( Don't know the difference between web server or CLI loading

Comment: how does it show ? can you run `php -i` from CLI to see the installed extension and version

Comment: for PHP7 the package is called `php7.0-curl`